# WordPress - enable search for custom DB

Tags: mysql, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-shortcode

I am new to WordPress, PHP, and SQL, not much knowledge of coding. I have a MySQL Table, data of a book's pages and lines as rows. The columns are SQ_no, Page_no, Line_no, Verse, VerseTranslationHindi, VerseTranslationEnglish etc. Pages are more than 1000, each page has 50+ verses (Or in this case - rows). I want to display all rows of each page in a post. I used PHP Code Snippets Plugin and a snippet contain this code to fetch data from the table.

```
global $wpdb; global $post; 
$post_slug=$post->post_name; 

$result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM book_db where Page_no='$post_slug'");

foreach ($result as $row) 
{
echo  $row->Verse;
 echo "</br>"; 
echo  $row->VerseTranslationHindi;
 echo "</br>";  
echo  $row->VerseTranslationEnglish;
 echo "</br>"; 
}

?>
```

This works great when I call snippet in a post and give it a slug, like page-1, page-2, etc.

However, the problem with this approach is, **the WordPress search box does not find any word from the DB**. (I guess it's because I have a custom DB. If I place the same data directly in a post, the search shows them ).

My question is, **how can I enable search for custom DB? Or is there any better way to do the same thing?**

I appreciate any help you can provide.